# firebase remote confige data fatch successfully but first time it return null value of my string data

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

if i open my game first time that time it return null and after quite and again restart game it will sucessfully show my accual value.
so please tell me what is the issue

i tried to print the value of this but it return null on my Mobile device but it is completly work in my PC

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
config.fetchAndActivate()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val updated = task.result
                // here get your result
                logD { "Fetch and activate succeeded, config params updated: $updated" }
            } else {
                logE { "Fetch failed" }
            }
        }
```